# Writing view for couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I have this document in couchdb, I wish to write a view which can emit key combination of original "_id" and the id within "Body" with the value as the body itself.

basically if "doc" is the json:

key [ _id, "key in Body" ]

value [ doc['_id']['Body'][key in Body]

[json Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOUyu.png)

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB has a detailed [guide to views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/index.html).

A views map function can emit multiple key-value pairs per document, so in your case you would emit each `doc.Body` entry.

```js
function(doc) {
  if (doc.Body) {
    // get an array of own property names in doc.Body
    var bodies = Object.keys(doc.Body);
    // loop over all the Body entries
    bodies.forEach(function (body) {
      // emit key-value for each entry
      emit([doc._id, body], bodies[body].body);
    });
  }
}
```

To get all bodies from `doc._id = "123"`:

```
http://my.couch.host/my-db/_design/docname/_view/viewname?startkey=["123"]&endkey=["123",{}]
```

To get the body of `doc.Body.abc` from `doc._id = "123"`:

```
http://my.couch.host/my-db/_design/docname/_view/viewname?startkey=["123","abc"]&endkey=["123","abc"]
```

See [views collation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html) and [complex keys](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html#complex-keys) for more information.